# Why is my program skipping over several lines of code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

This is a portion of my page load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string v = Request.QueryString["File"];
    string q = Request.QueryString["Quote"];
    if (v != null)
    {
        int temp;
        if (int.TryParse(v, out temp))
        {
            FileStruct fs = BlobDA.GetBlobFileStruct(temp);
            string url = FileStorage.getBlobFile(fs);
            Response.Redirect(url);
        }
    }

    if (q != null)
    {
        QuoteInfo qiQuote = Utility.getQuoteObject(int.Parse(q));
        Session.Add("Quote", qiQuote);
    }

    // CODE BELOW DOES ISN'T RUN  -----------

    QuoteInfo objQuote = (QuoteInfo)Session["Quote"];
    lstLouverStruct = objQuote.LstLouverStruct;
    structSpecs = objQuote.StructSpecs;

    structCustomer = objQuote.StructCustomer;
    structVendor = objQuote.StructVendor;

    // --------------------------------------            

    var dt = Utility.GetDatatableList(lstLouverStruct);
    var html = Utility.BuildString("Dims", dt);
    phDims.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
```

The code in between the commented lines is not running.

I can't see the variables from the specified code in the debug window so it is skipping the code below from the `if (q != null)` statement to the `var dt = ...`

I have noticed that when debugging a page load where `q != null`, which basically means that a query string containing a quote number was passed, and I send the quote number to a data access class method that recreates the `QuoteInfo` object, then I add that object to the session variable. Then, in the skipped code, I take that object out of the session variable and do work with it. Basically, if `q == null` is `true`, then there is already a session variable quote so that condition is there to change objects in the session variable. Anyhow, I am following the code in the debugger it sets the session variable then skips over the mentioned code.

Not sure if this is pertinent but for some reason, all my variables in the debugger seem to be optimized out even though I am debugging with optimization off.

Any help would be appreciated

[image: Snippit off debug panel]

Update ------------------

I was using debug mode.
[image: My panel reads debug]

Anyhow build re-build and clean seems to have fixed the problems Thanks Jason

Comment: Any exceptions happening?  Put a try/catch to check.

Comment: don't run under release build

Comment: Seems like a release build that is optimized. Use Debug builds if you want to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the PDB that the debugger is using does not actually match the byte code being run. One of the most common causes is debugging a release build, as the comments have mentioned. Other problems include old/stale dll's being referenced, and old pdb files that are not being cleaned up. Try each of these fixes(in order of severity) :

1. Running a debug build
2. Build > Rebuild
3. Build > Clean
4. Manually deleting all the generated PDB files.
5. Deleting the whole directory and checking it out again (Assuming you are using source control)